# How to measure live progress on code runtime in R if it isn't a for-loop but any other function?

Tags: r, runtime, progress-bar

Is there a way to attach a progress bar like `winProgressBar` or the like to a chunk of code that is not a for-loop?

For instance, and to keep things very simple, let's say my function is just `Sys.sleep(60)` and I wanted a progress bar that let's me know how R is getting on with its nap.

Another example would be a bunch of lines of code like so:

```
my.data <- data.frame(var = rnorm(1000000000))
Sys.sleep(5)
hist(my.data$var)
Sys.sleep(5)
```

In reality, I'm running a large dictionary on an even larger amount of text data, using Quanteda's `tokens_lookup()`.

I'm not entirely sure how that all would work and what a progress bar would report on (Percent of total time R will have needed once it is done?), but perhaps there is a way. ... Well, is there?

Comment: Not really. If the function isn't written to track progress, you can't really change that from the outside. It's basically the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) -- a computer can't know for sure when any code will end unless it's written to track it.

Comment: @MrFlick Even if it _is_ written to track it a function often can't know for sure that a certain calculation it runs in between progress messages will halt, as anyone who has encountered a frozen progress bar will attest.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, though it is unfortunate. I guess my question would then be what makes progress on a function quantifiable. And if progress on a for-loop is measured as "I'm now done with `i`, moving on to `i+1`! Keep you posted until I reach `k`!" then shouldn't there be a way to measure progress say on the application of a dictionary on text using sub-dimensions of that dictionary as steps or the on the creation of a data.frame using every new column that is created as steps towards completion?

Comment: @FabianHabersack you are profiling/optimizing your code, take a look at `profviz`.